# How can I extract elementary values with ElementTree in Python?

Tags: python, xml, tags, elementtree

I try to extract values attributes (ex. 'Filename') of that XML file in Python.
Can you help me ?

Here is the MC 'Librarytest.xml' file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<MPL Version="2.0" Title="Library">
<Item>
<Field Name="Filename">Y:\Styx\08 - Styx - Snowblind8. Snowblind.flac</Field>
<Field Name="Name">Snowblind</Field>
<Field Name="Artist">Styx</Field>
<Field Name="Album">Paradise Theater</Field>
<Field Name="Genre">Rock</Field>
</Item>
<Item>
<Field Name="Filename">Y:\David Gilmour\04 A Boat Lies Waiting.flac</Field>
<Field Name="Name">A Boat Lies Waiting</Field>
<Field Name="Artist">David Gilmour</Field>
<Field Name="Album">Rattle That Lock (Deluxe)</Field>
<Field Name="Genre">Progressive</Field>
</Item>
</MPL>
```

I try this :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_file = 'C:/Users/ClientMD/Downloads/MC Librarytest.xml'
tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()
for each in root.findall('.//Field'):
    rating = each.find('.//Filename')
    print ('Nothing' if rating is None else rating.text)
```

and I obtain :

Nothing
...
Nothing

Comment: what are you using Python?

Comment: Better show us the whole code, not just a portion

Comment: if your objective is to get `FileName` then you can directly get that attribute by `.//Field[@Name="Filename"]` and your code would be like `for each in root.findall('.//Field[@Name="Filename"]'):
    rating=each.text
    print ('Nothing' if rating is None else rating)`

Answer (score 0):

##### Like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_file = 'C:/Users/ClientMD/Downloads/MC Librarytest.xml'
tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()
for each in root.findall('.//Field[@Name="Filename"]'):
    rating = each.text
    print ('Nothing' if rating is None else rating)
```

##### Output

```
Y:\Styx\08 - Styx - Snowblind8. Snowblind.flac
Y:\David Gilmour\04 A Boat Lies Waiting.flac
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles ! But if I want to extract an other variable (ex. "Artist"), I can't recover in the same loop !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab more elements and keep them under a single item context - you can use the below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<MPL Version="2.0" Title="Library">
<Item>
<Field Name="Filename">Y:\Styx\\08 - Styx - Snowblind8. Snowblind.flac</Field>
<Field Name="Name">Snowblind</Field>
<Field Name="Artist">Styx</Field>
<Field Name="Album">Paradise Theater</Field>
<Field Name="Genre">Rock</Field>
</Item>
<Item>
<Field Name="Filename">Y:\David Gilmour\\04 A Boat Lies Waiting.flac</Field>
<Field Name="Name">A Boat Lies Waiting</Field>
<Field Name="Artist">David Gilmour</Field>
<Field Name="Album">Rattle That Lock (Deluxe)</Field>
<Field Name="Genre">Progressive</Field>
</Item>
</MPL>'''

INTERESTING_NAMES = ['Filename','Artist']
data = []
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for item in root.findall('.//Item'):
    temp = {}
    for name in INTERESTING_NAMES:
        temp[name] = item.find(f'Field[@Name="{name}"]').text
    data.append(temp)
print(data)
```

output

```
[{'Filename': 'Y:\\Styx\\08 - Styx - Snowblind8. Snowblind.flac', 'Artist': 'Styx'}, {'Filename': 'Y:\\David Gilmour\\04 A Boat Lies Waiting.flac', 'Artist': 'David Gilmour'}]
```

Comment: Levy - if my answer helped you - please accept it.

Comment: I'm a new user. How can I accept it ?